# Pandas: Effective way to check if a certain value exists in all columns and replace only that value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

For a specific value: `-999.00`, I am trying to check if it exists in any column of my dataframe. If `-999.00` exists in any column then I want to create a new column and replace only `-999.00` values with `1.00`. For example, below is my dataframe and the output I am trying to get.

```
Dataframe:
    MMC         MET_lep     MASS_Vis    Pt_H        Y
0   138.70      51.65       97.82       0.91        0
1   160.93      68.78       103.23      -999.00     0
2   -999.00     162.17      125.95      -999.00     0
3   143.90      81.41       80.94       -999.00     1
4   175.86      16.91       134.80      -999.00     0


Output I am trying to get:
    MMC       MMC_mv    MET_lep   MASS_Vis   Pt_H       Pt_H_mv    Y
0   138.70    138.70    51.65     97.82      0.91       0.91       0
1   160.93    160.93    68.78     103.23     -999.00    1.00       0
2   -999.00   1.00      162.17    125.95     -999.00    1.00       0
3   143.90    143.90    81.41     80.94      -999.00    1.00       1
4   175.86    175.86    16.91     134.80     -999.00    1.00       0
```

Below is my code but it does not do anything nor gives any error:

```
for column in df.columns.tolist():
    if (-999.00 in df[column]) == True:
        df[column+'_mv'] = df.column.apply(lambda x: 1.00 if x == -999.00 else x)

print(df.head(3))
```

Thanks. I appreciate all the help. Please let me know if any additional information is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
# get column names which contain -999
cols = (df == -999).any()[lambda x: x].index

# create new columns for these columns and replace -999 with -1
df[cols + "_mv"] = df[cols].where(df[cols] != -999, 1)
df
```

[image]

Or if you'd like to write a for loop and update:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if (df[col] == -999).any():
        df[col+"_mv"] = df[col].replace(-999, 1)
```

BTW your solution doesn't work because of two reasons:

1) `-999 in df[column]` doesn't check if values contain -999 as you expected but index, a series is more like a dictionary in this case;

2) since `column` is a string in the for loop, you can't access the column with `df.column` which is interpreting `column` as an attribute, you need `df[column]` instead;

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying problem in my solution.